# Matching letters with specific intervals in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I was wondering if there was a simple method in Python2.7 to have a string of letters (such as MVMGLGVLLLVFVLGLGLTPPTLAQDNSRYTHFLTQHYDAKPQGRDDRYCESIMRRRGLT) and to determine if in it there ocurred certain letters with x strings between (i.e. an "M" and a "V" with 3 other letters (any other letters) between them. This is done to align protein sequences, but I am seeing no way of doing this

Comment: You should try using regex (python `re` module) : https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html and https://regex101.com/#python for testing. Try to do what you want with regex, and if you don't manage to, come back, with the code you wrote.

Comment: Unless you're looking to reinvent the wheel, I believe you can do protein alignments using [BioPython](http://biopython.org/).

Comment: @HolyDanna was trying to understand what in fact it was that I had to use from re, but all clear now

Comment: @DanRussell, I know it would be the best answer, but I'm only utilizing a very small part of the alignments and the output wasn't the best

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the comment says, regex is your friend.
Here's a sample to find any blocks or M then any three letters then V

`M[A-Z]{3}V` looks for `'M'` then any of 'A' up to 'Z' (`[A-Z]`) three times (`{3}`) followed by `'V`' so this will find the specific thing you mention.

```
>>> import re

>>> s = 'MVMGLGVLLLVFVLGLGLTPPTLAQDNSRYTHFLTQHYDAKPQGRDDRYCESIMRRRGLT'
>>> matches = re.findall("M[A-Z]{3}V", s)
>>> for match in matches:
...   print match
...
MGLGV
```